# Вызов функции из класса

Tags: php, классы

**Всем доброго времени суток.**

---------------------ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ---------------------

Я работаю с движком сайта на php. С него-то и началось моё изучение php. Проблем не было, писал новые модули к сайту и всё работало. Всё было прекрасно до тех пор, пока несколько дней назад я не решил разобраться как устроен движок, и как с нуля самому написать полноценный движок сайта. Начал понемногу разбираться и вроде бы всё получается. Но я наткнулся на преграду №1.

---------------------ПРОБЛЕМА---------------------

Проблема заключается в следующем. У меня есть такой код:

```
class ShowGeneralPage
{
    public function show()
    {
        global $tpl_vars;

        ShowGeneralPage::tpl_vars_add(array(
            'key_1'    => 'value_1',
            'key_2'    => 'value_2'
        ));

        echo $tpl_vars;
    }
    function tpl_vars_add($display_vars)
    {
        global $tpl_vars;

        ...некий код...
        $tpl_vars = "некое значение";
    }
}
```

Я хочу обратить внимание на сам метод вызова функции `"tpl_vars_add"`. Я подключаюсь к классу из файла `index.php`. Класс `ShowGeneralPage` находится в другом файле. При подключении к классу я автоматически вызываю функцию `"show"`. В функции `"show"`, с помощью конструкции `"ShowGeneralPage::tpl_vars_add();"` я вызываю функцию `"tpl_vars_add"`. И всё работает отлично. А если я просто напишу `"tpl_vars_add();"`, то ничего не произойдёт. Я же вызываю эту функцию в том же самом классе в котором нахожусь. Как мне заставить php-обработчик вызвать мою функцию по её названию, а не по её пути в классе? В движке сайта, с которым я работал именно так было реализовано, и без всяких проблем работало. У меня же - нет. Подозреваю, что в том движке где-то было указано, как правильно обрабатывать такие моменты. Какие у вас будут мысли на этот счёт?
Заранее благодарю всех за внимание.

Comment: так ?

    $this->tpl_vars_add() ? 

global - **плохо**

Comment: `$this->tpl_vars_add()` не работает. Проверял.
Почему `global` это плохо? Напротив - очень удобно, если нужно чтоб эта переменная была доступна на всех страницах сайта.

Comment: >Почему global это плохо? Напротив - очень удобно, если нужно чтоб эта переменная была доступна на всех страницах сайта

почему переходить дорогу на красный плохо? Напротив - очень удобно,  не нужно ждать зелёного, взял и пошел

Comment: вам статично её вызвать надо или что ? можете собрать маленький пример на ideone который демонстрирует проблему ? http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: У меня есть переменная в классе. Из этого же класса мне нужно её вызвать. На данный момент срабатывает только такая конструкция `"ShowGeneralPage::tpl_vars_add();"`, а мне надо добиться вызова этой переменной через конструкцию `"tpl_vars_add();"`, чтоб не указывать имя класса, к которому принадлежит данная функция, так как она находится внутри того же класса.

Comment: но вообще это вопрос скорее холиварный, проблема с  global в конкретно вашем коде в том,  что вам в каждой функции придется тащить эту переменную и помнить где она глобальная, помнить, что она может измениться и тд. к тому-же судя по всему вы объекты не используете а используете класс как контейнер для функций (на библиотеку похоже)

в смысле переменная в классе $tpl_vars - глобальная ?  у вас там есть метод, как вы вызываете show() ?

[вот то что вы пытаетесь сделать](http://ideone.com/L9Dhdt) но это не ооп вообще.

Comment: Ну насчёт глобальных переменных: мне они как разу нужны, для того, чтоб их можно было изменить или получить к ним доступ, с любой страницы сайта.
Насчёт классов: я использую класс, как отдельную страницу сайта. Например в адресной строке пишу такой текст `index.php?page=name`. Открывается страница `index.php`, которая принимает значение элемента `page` (например значение `name`) и вызывает класс, который описывает страницу `name`. А глобальная переменная `$tpl_vars`, это переменная, которая содержит массив переменных, для вывода в шаблон.

Comment: @intro94 это ужасно. вы думаете class это такое модное слово, которое сразу превращает ваш код в ООП а программу делает конфеткой ? Да если бы у вас все было в процедурном стиле описано, это выглядело бы лучше чем то что вы сделали. правда, нет слов, я ещё ни разу не видел чтобы так издевались над идеей ООП.

---

@intro94, а я думаю (если они конечно прям так делают) , дураков везде хватает.

Comment: Спасибо за ценный совет. Я делал так, как мне удобнее. И такой способ используется в движке он-лайн игры, с которым я работаю. Не думаю, что в разработчиках этой игры сидят дураки.

<hr />
@eicto, а я считаю, что это дело каждого. Своё мнение навязывать не надо. Каждый делает так как ему удобно. Если вам это не нравится, это не значит что код написан дураками. Такое применение очень удобно, особенно когда требуется написать страницу отдельными модулями. Да вы посмотрите на любой движок. Короче - это на вкус и цвет. Вас попросили найти решение проблемы, а не обсуждать метод написания сайта!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в index.php Вы вызываете ShowGeneralPage::show() то для вызова внутри show() по любому потребуется прописывать нахождение метода с именем класса. Если же конструкция в index.php будет вида:

```
$ShowGeneralPage = new ShowGeneralPage;
$ShowGeneralPage->show();
```

то внутри show() Вы сможете обратиться к tpl_vars_add() по команде $this->tpl_vars_add();

Вызов статического метода( ShowGeneralPage::show() ) вызывает только тот метод который указан в выводе, без доступа к остальным методам и объектам класса.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вот вызов самого класса:

    require('includes/pages/class.ShowGeneralPage.php');
    $pageObj = new ShowGeneralPage;
    $pageObj->show();

Да, этот вариант работает. Просто тот движок, с которым я работал, позволял запускать функцию без команды `$this->my_function();`. Вот я и хотел узнать, как можно сделать это вручную.

Comment: @intro94 еще раз http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: @eicto ещё раз повторяю: меня не интересовала конструкция `$this->my_function();` или `self::my_function();`. Это у меня прекрасно работает. Меня интересовал прямой вызов функции с помощью конструкции `my_function();`

Comment: Для прямого вызова функции вынесите её из класса тогда она и будет доступна по конструкции my_function(); Но тога это уже не ООП код а процедурный. Вам решать как писать :-)

Comment: Я понял. За ответы спасибо. Только странно тогда. Тот движок игры, который я использовал, он написан на ООП, и в таком же виде, как пишу я (я пишу по примеру того движка). И там как раз вызывается функция по той конструкции, которой хочу воспользоваться я. Структура сайта именно та, какая и у меня. Идёт вызов класса

    $pageObj = new ShowGeneralPage;
    $pageObj->show();

а из функции `show();` вызывается функция `my_function` по конструкции `my_function();`.

Comment: [вот пример с this](http://ideone.com/RW5GhW) 

[вот пример с self](http://ideone.com/L9Dhdt)

что вас не устраивает ? в обоих случаях вызывается метод tpl_vars_add

Comment: @intro94, в PHP есть только два способа обращения к функции, которые Вам продемонстрировали. Поведение, о котором говорите Вы, не является нормальным для этого языка, поэтому не удивительно, что Вас никто не понимает и не дал ответа на Ваш вопрос. Если функция действительно вызывается подобным образом, то это ОЧЕНЬ странно и надо копать исходники этой вашей игры.

Comment: @terantul спасибо. Вот теперь понятно. Буду копать в сторону исходников. :)